# How to keep same profile image if no edits are made

Tags: php

I've made a fairly simple profile upload function.

You choose the image and you submit, and it works. However I now want to give my user the option to change the profile image. I've made this form for when the user hits the button for changing profile settings, it allows the user to change his profile name or his profile image:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  action="imageinsert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username" >NAME:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-7">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>" name="username"> 
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">IMAGE:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-5">
       <p class ="formspacehack"></p>
       <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SAVE</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

My problem is, if the user opens this form and changes his name but do not select any image, then it will upload a non existing image or in other words: delete the currently image because it uploads null.

I'm thinking I can do some kind of tricks to my action page? 
I already made on my action page so the profile image is an default picture if a image is null.

```
   $file = $_FILES['file'];

$name = $file['name'];

if(empty($name)){
  $name = "optionimage.png";
};
$path = "./images/" . basename($name);
```

However the default image is not a solution for me if an user already has a image and opens the edit form but decides not change it anyways. Then I want the user to keep having the same image as he had before opening the form.

EDIT (My upload to db code):

```
$sqltwo = "UPDATE `users` SET `image` = '$path' WHERE `users`.`id` = '$id'";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sqltwo)){

    echo "Image uploaded successfully.";
    $newURL = "profile.php";


    header("Refresh:2; url=profile.php");
}  else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the part or your code that uploads updated data to the database

Comment: Can you add the part or your code that uploads updated data to the database

Comment: Well, you yourself say that you have a second condition indicating when you _not_ want to replace the stored reference: if the user already has an image set. So simply add a second condition, so a second `if` statement checking exactly that.

Comment: @hazelcodes I now added the part to my post

Comment: @arkascha I have that thought in my head but can't figure it out, because if the user hits "save" then it will upload a "null" file, its like it overrules. Does that make sense? (I have a hard time explaining it..)

Comment: Where do you obtain the variable `$id` for the update statement?

Comment: @RamRaider does that matter? all that is working fine. My images are uploading successfully and to the right user.  If it matters I'm happy to show it, but I want to try to keep my post as simple as possible. 

To let you know, I'm getting it using sessions for when the user logs in.

Comment: @Chao1920 you just need to check if the file isset as @mooga suggested  and is not equal to an empty string `''` before updating

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if there's an image are added or not 
and if not you don't update that field, so you have to seperate the fields quires.

```
if( isset($_POST['file']) and $_POST['file']){
   $file = $_FILES['file'];
}
```